# Instruments crashed on startup iPad Mini

Tags: ios, eclipse, ipad, appium

I am new to Appium IOS testing. I have some scripts which I am running with Eclipse and help of Appium on my iPad mini. The scripts were running quite good, but recently only I'm facing this issue.

> Error launching instruments: Instruments crashed on startup

[Issue Log](https://www.dropbox.com/s/mz6j2fg7nzbo9u9/Issue%20Log.rtf?dl=0)

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Please post a summary of the issue, along with any error messages. Please post your code, so we can see what caused the error. What have you tried so far, to fix it? http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: @TomLord i added everything in that document. I tried posting it inline but the text length was longer that the permitted text length

Comment: A **59-page log file** is an inappropriate way to describe your problem, and ask for help. Please refer back to the above link I posted. Where is your code? Where is a *summary* of the error message? What have you tried so far?

Comment: Error launching instruments: Instruments crashed on startup. Clearly written thats the error. If you can help. Please do, i know the way of posting questions

Comment: **WHERE IS YOUR CODE?** If you will not provide enough information for anyone to answer, then I'll vote to close.

Comment: I'm not able to connect the simple device, what would code do here

Comment: OK, let me rephrase this: How can I reproduce your problem?

Comment: When i'm connecting a device to Appium and running with eclipse it crashes. The issue probably is with IOS >9, IOS 8 is working fine

Comment: Have you faced any such issue?

Answer (score 0):

Within your log file you are obtaining an error

`WebKit Threading Violation - initial use of WebKit from a secondary thread.`

This is a common issue if you do not have UI Automation turned on on your device.
To turn it on go to `Settings > Developer` and enable UI Automation

Comment: It is enabled. The issues is with certain devices not all.